# Div padding-top difference between Firefox and Chrome/Safari

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, firefox, safari

I'm working on a website and I'm having an issue in declaring CSS `padding-top`.

My problem is that the padding is rendered in a different way in Firefox respect to Chrome or Safari. I saw this as soon as I switched my `navbar`div to `position: fixed`.

Here it is a JSFiddle with basic code which shows the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/8puCW/3/

Is there a way to maintain fixed the header/topbar and the navbar without having differences in rendering?

thanks.

Comment: Wouldn't changing the top style on .main from 45 to 37 fix this?

Comment: You can do a CSS reset; ` * { margin: 0; padding: 0; }`

Comment: @j08691 do not consider that white strip. try to open the jsfiddle with firefox and you'll see that "menu" is positioned in a different way (quite below "my content").

Comment: @TylerH the CSS reset does not solve the problem. You can try by yourself on jsfiddle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

since you use the position:fixed (http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_position.asp) for the .navbar, get rid of the padding-top to position the element and use the top property, as shown in this Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8puCW/9/. I've tested it in FF Mac and it is consistent.

```
.navbar {
    position: fixed;
    background: #D0D1D0;
    float: left;
    text-align: center;
    top: 54px; /*UPDATE HERE*/
    width: 200px;
    height: 100%;
    padding-top:20px; /*UPDATE HERE*/  }
```